# Cannot resolve symbol 'from'

Tags: java, android

In this JsonResponse

```
private void handleReserveResponse (final String res) {

        if (res != null){

            try {

                JSONObject objResponce = new JSONObject(res);
                String success = objResponce.getString("success");
                if (success.equals("true")) {

                    JSONArray arrdata = objResponce.getJSONArray("disponibilidad");
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrdata.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject objdata = arrdata.getJSONObject(i);
                        String listDatesA = objdata.getString("slot_date");

                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                        dateA = format.parse(listDatesA);

                        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendar.setTime(dateA);

                        CalendarDay calendarDay = new CalendarDay.from(calendar);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else {
                DialogAlert.show_alert_dialog(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.result_null_msg));
            }

    }
```

I want to get different dates to store them in `String listDatesA`  and convert them to `Date`

But in the line `CalendarDay calendarDay = new CalendarDay.from(calendar);`

`.from` is placed in red and shows the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'from'`

In another project probe this code and did not have this error. I try File-> Invalidate catches / Restar but not work. How can i solve it please

Comment: `new CalendarDay.from` is not valid Java. Did you mean just `CalendayDay.from`?

Comment: It's a static method, so you can't call it from an object, but from the class. Try: `CalendarDay calendarDay = CalendarDay.from(calendar);` (remove 'new'). See [the documentation, here](https://prolificinteractive.github.io/material-calendarview/com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/CalendarDay.html).

Comment: As a note, if you were to want to call a method from a new Object, you would do so like this: `int foo = new ArrayList<>().getSize();` You can call the method right after the constructor, assuming you don't mind the object not being referenced anywhere else, or if you are using a builder that returns itself on chained method calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
CalendarDay calendarDay = new CalendarDay.from(calendar);
```

to this:

```
CalendarDay calendarDay = CalendarDay.from(calendar);
```

Comment: Please consider adding more explanation/insight to your answer, because this was already covered in the comments.